# Cannot Find Symbol - Classes inside same package

Tags: java, compilation, package, classpath, symbols

I was having fun coding in Java, until for some reason javac stopped compiling my code. I googled about classpath, and set my CLASSPATH to `/root/java`. It was not set before that.

My package is in the `/.../t` directory with name `centralServer` (i.e. `/.../t/centralServer`).

Now it is compiling from the `/.../t` directory with the command `javac centralServer/TestSSData.java`. (The command is called from the `/.../t` directory). The output it gives is

> `Cannot find symbol`

If I run the command from `/.../t/centralServer` with `javac TestSSData.java` I get as output:

> `File not found.`

Point me the way for any roads I can follow to fix this please?

---

I removed the package statement and now it compiles. However this is not the way I would like to fix it...

Comment: I promise a nuclear blow-up is not the solution that you are looking for :) Hopefully we can help solve some of this here!

Comment: Can you provide us with the entire `path`? You are using, and the location of your `java` folder in your `Programs`? Also, what operating system are you using?

Comment: These cannot be the full error messages, please post the entire messages.

Comment: @Dici:  Its not the code that is wrong. I have solved this cannot find symbol problem after reading another post here on stackoverflow, but now its not working anymore for some reason.
Is there a way to add screenshots?

Comment: @T.Woody: I know a nuclear blow-up is not the solution but I am on so much pressure to get this done. I tried implementing the solution in C and changed to Java 1 week before the deadline.

~/Documents/RC/Projecto/Java/t/centralServer

What do you mean with "he location of your java folder in your Programs"? 

I am using ubuntu

Comment: Could it be because of missing imports? Shouldn't java files in the same package be accessible to any other file in the same package without any import?

Comment: @Dici
javac "TestSSData.java" (in directory: /home/testingwarhead/Documents/RC/Projecto/Java/t/centralServer)
TestSSData.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
  StorageServerData SSd;
  ^
  symbol:   class StorageServerData
  location: class TestFileData